# flterProperty or filter to match a property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

with this model

```
App.Customer  = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string' ),
  postalCode: DS.attr('string' ),
});
```

and this controller :

```
App.CustomersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,

    searchResults: function() {
            var searchText = this.get('searchText');
            var regex = new RegExp(searchText);

             if (!searchText) { return this; }

             return this.filterProperty('name',searchText);

    }.property('searchText')
});
```

I can filter the list of customers that have a name of the value of searchText

How can I change this to return a list of customers where the name matches searchtext (if searchText was "foo" and I had customers with names of "foobar", "fooinc" and "foo" in the list it would return these three ?

I have tried to use the filter() method

```
return this.filter(function(item,index,enumerable){
        // some code
     });
```

but item.name is always undefined (for each of the 100 or so items in the array)

thanks

**UPDATE**

I got it working with this code

```
searchResults: function() {
    var searchText = this.get('searchText');
    var self = this;
    var patt1 = new RegExp(self.searchText,"i");

     if (!searchText) { return this;}

     return this.filter(function(item,index,enumerable){
        var data = item.get('name');
        return patt1.test(data);
     });

}.property('searchText')
```

which is very similar to the answer I selected.

thank you.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have in your template an `input` helper like this:

```
{{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}
```

assuming further you have a list of items that should be filtered depending on the `searchText` specified in the text field:

```
<ul>
{{#each place in searchResults}}
  <li><strong>{{place.name}}</strong></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

And here a sample controller that filters the `content` (re-invoking the `each` helper) whenever the `searchText` property changes which is bound to the `value` of the `input` helper:

```
App.PlacesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  searchText: '',
  searchResults: function() {
    var searchText = this.get('searchText');
    var regExPattern = '\\b'+searchText+'\\b'; 
    var regexp = new RegExp(regExPattern,'gi');
    return this.get('content').filter(function(place){
      return place.get('name').match(regexp);
    });
  }.property('searchText')
});
```

> Note: how you want the search text to match your properties values is up to you, this example shows just one possible way.

See here for a working [demo](http://jsbin.com/EwEwOcE/4/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have got it working with something very similar (see update). I was curious to know the difference between **_return this.filter"_** and **_return this.get('content').filter_**

Comment: this.get('content') is or will be deprecated. Use this.get('model')